# Getting all users mentioned in a tweet text and their user ID's

Tags: python, tweepy

When I search for a tweet containing certain words, I want to check for users mentioned in those tweets that say specifically 'follow @someoneSo' so I could keep track of them and check out their profiles if they seem like relevant accounts, and hopefully, follow some accounts that I like at the end of it.

Is there something similar to Discord's message.mentions.users where it returns a list of users mentioned in a tweet text?

For example, if a tweet text = 'dvffegregre rg ADQEW follow @chad @lee efkneknen' or tweet text = 'dvffegregre rg ADQEW follow these guys @chad @lee efkneknen', my script would be able to follow @chad and @lee

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
text = 'dvffegregre rg ADQEW follow @chad @lee efkneknen'
textlist = text.split(' ')
users = []
if 'follow' in textlist:
    for subtext in textlist:
        if subtext.startswith('@'):
            API.create_friendship(subtext.strip('@'))
```

I think this should work for your purpose.

Comment: it works! the startswith and createfriendship part was what i was looking for thanks

Comment: just wondering now how to make it smarter, because seems like tweets such as "follow,like and retweet @ plasconuganda timeline to hear more about it #businessbehindfashion @ arapapabysanta  @ plasconuganda  @ ugaman01" make me follow everyone when i should only be wanting to follow @ plasconuganda, which is the person that is relevant

Comment: You can just modify the code to follow the first person mentioned after the word "follow" then break. And you should split for comma (and anything you think may come after the follow word) too. Or you can search for subtext "follow" in textlist.  Please let me know if you need any help with the modification.